# Some Chinese characters can no show using ctex

Tags: overleaf, ctex

I use overleaf to edit my CV, but I find a character "珅" in Chinese cannot be shown in the compiled PDF. I also try XeCJK, but it doesn't work too.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
珅
\end{document}
```

Comment: One way this can happen is if your font does not have the character. If you add `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your document, do you get a warning message on the console about your font not containing the character?

Comment: Without `\tracinglostchars=2`, TeX (in a bad decision decades ago that we are now stuck with) will silently log a warning message in the middle of your `.log` file and put a blank space where the character should be.

Answer (score 3):

The default fontset (`fandol`) loaded by `ctex` and `xeCJK` may not have glyphs for many archaic Chinese characters. If you're compiling this on Overleaf, you can use the `fontset=ubuntu` option to load Noto Serif CJK SC:

```
\usepackage[UTF8,fontset=ubuntu]{ctex}
```

Or if you prefer to load the font explicitly:

```
\usepackage{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC} % or some other font that has the glyph
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. It solves my question in an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to expand on imnothere’s fine answer with a few best practices.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[UTF8, fontset=none]{ctex}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

%% Noto CJK fonts available at
%%  https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale=1.0]
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}

\begin{document}
珅
\end{document}
```

- You want `\tracinglostchars=2` so that TeX will give you a warning when your font is missing a character. Without this command, the warning will be silently buried in the middle of your `.log` file.
- In LuaLaTeX as of 2020, you need to load your CJK fonts with the `Renderer=HarfBuzz`, or you will get an out-of-memory error. XeTeX uses HarfBuzz by default and works fine.  XeLaTeX should give you a benign warning if it sees `Renderer=`.
- You probably want a `Scale=` option if you are mixing different fonts.
- You might wish to set sans-serif and monospace fonts as well.
- If you would be overloading the font set from the package anyway, you can skip loading one with `fontset=none`.